# Effects for TextArea letters (Flex)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

How do I add effects (shadow, glow) to all letters in the component TextArea (Spark 4)?

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear.  I was suggesting that you could use a custom font which already has the effects you want to add as part of the font.

Answer (score 1):

I see it is an old question, but since i fell in the same problem today i'm posting my solution.

You can access to the `RichEditableText` component of the `TextArea` using `textDisplay` as stated [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TextArea.html):

> The RichEditableText can be accessed as textDisplay and the Scroller
>   as scroller

`RichEditableText` is extended from `UIComponent`, so `filters`, which can be applied to `UIComponents` (["You can apply filters to any visual component that is derived from UIComponent"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/RichEditableText.html)), can be applied to it.

In order to apply, for example, a `DropShadowFilter` to all letters in the component `myTextArea:TextArea` i have used the following lines of code:

```
var richTextComponent:UIComponent = myTextArea.textDisplay as UIComponent;
var shadow:spark.filters.DropShadowFilter = new spark.filters.DropShadowFilter;
richTextComponent.filters = [shadow];
```

Hope this helps someone :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it using Flex (or at least I never have). You would need to do it using AS3

```
<s:Label id="label1" text="Shadow Me" />

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    import flash.filters.*;

    private function creationComplete():void{
        var dropshadow:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter( 3,90,0x000000,.5,4,4,3,3 );
        this.label1.filters = [ dropshadow ];
    }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
contentBackgroundAlpha="0" borderVisible="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

By using Filter class we can apply shadow glow effect for a s:TextArea component. The sample code is:

```
<s:TextArea contentBackgroundAlpha="0" borderAlpha="0">
        <s:filters>
              <s:DropShadowFilter distance="5" angle="45" color="#666666"/>
        </s:filters>
        <s:content>
              Testing text area content
        </s:content>
  </s:TextArea>
```

Refer the link http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/flex/flex4/components/filters.html for applying more filters (DropShadowFilter, GlowFilter, BlurFilter and BevelFilter).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a skin to your TextArea component then add a shadow to the RichEditableText inside the skin.

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:DropShadowFilter id="shadow2"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:RichEditableText id="textDisplay" heightInLines="10" widthInChars="15"  filters="{[shadow2]}"/>
```

It worked for me, you have just to adjust the shadow to have a nice look.